# Out of Memory Error when using graphics

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory

I have been making a game for my games development class but due to the limitations in college we have to create a game using Visual Basic and no plugins, so I only have GDI+ to work with.

I have run into an error where it will run out of memory and the game stops running, the error is at line 312 - "_backBufferGr.DrawImage(_backbuffer, 0, 0, _resWidth, _resHeight)"

I think it may be due to the images that are being spawned aren't being cleared but I'm not sure as I have only been coding for about 3 months. If anyone can help that would be very appreciated. I have attached the code below - the classes are in separate files in my project.

Here is an image of my error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfMSi.jpg

and as text:

```
System.OutOfMemory: Out of memory.  
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 Status)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 Width, Int32 height)
  at SpaceInvaders.Spaceinvaders.DrawGraphics()
```

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO

Public Class Spaceinvaders
'Star Generation Variables
ReadOnly _random As New Random
Private ReadOnly _r As New Random
Private ReadOnly _stars As New List(Of Point)

'Sound Variabless
Public Shared Intsound As Integer = 0
Public Shared Snd As New Sounds

'Graphics varibles 
Dim _backbuffer As Bitmap
Dim _backBufferGr As Graphics
Public Shared Gr As Graphics
Shared _sourceRec As Rectangle

'View Port Variables
Dim _resWidth As Int16 = 700
Dim _resHeight As Int16 = 650
Dim _paused As Boolean = False
Dim _pauseNum As Int16 = 0
Dim _pausedText As Int16 = 40
Dim _mouseX, _mouseY As Int16

'Key Detection
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Int16) As Int16
Public Function GetKeyState(ByVal key1 As Int16) As Boolean

    Dim s As Int16
    s = GetAsyncKeyState(key1)
    If s = 0 Then Return False
    Return True

End Function

'Character Variables
Dim _bmpPlayer As Bitmap
Public Shared PlayerW, PlayerH As Int16
Public Shared XPos As Int16 = 0
Public Shared YPos As Int16 = 0
Dim _movementSpeed As Int16 = 8
Dim _moveDir As Int16 = 0
Dim _lastDir As Int16 = 0

'Fire Variables
Dim _fire As Boolean
Dim _bulletArray(100000) As Bullet
Dim _bulletNum As Int16 = 0
Dim _cooldown As Int16
Public Shared Points As Int32 = 0
Public Shared EnemiesKilled As Int16 = 0
Public Shared ExploArray(100000) As Explo
Public Shared ExploNum As Int16 = 0

'Enemy Variables
Dim _spawnNum As Int16
Public Shared EnemyArray(100000) As Enemies
Public Shared EnemyNum As Int16 = 0
Public Shared Lives As Int16 = 3
Dim SpawnSpd As Int16 = 30

'Other Variables
Dim _isRunning As Boolean = True
Public Shared CollitionDetc As New StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath() & "\" & "Detection" & ".Log")
Public Function FadeInImage(ByVal bmp As Bitmap, ByVal opacity As Single) As Bitmap
    Dim bmp2 As New Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    opacity = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(opacity, 1.0F))
    Using ia As New ImageAttributes
        Dim cm As New ColorMatrix
        cm.Matrix33 = opacity
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm)
        Dim destpoints() As PointF = {New Point(0, 0), New Point(bmp.Width, 0), New Point(0, bmp.Height)}
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2)
            g.DrawImage(bmp, destpoints, New RectangleF(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return bmp2
End Function


'Form Events
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Show()
    Focus()

    'Create Stars - 300 is the Number of Stars
    CreateStarField(300)

    'Start Music
    Intsound += 1
    With Snd
        .Name = "Sound" & Intsound
        .PlaySound(1, True)
    End With

    'This creates the graphics and the backbuffer, along with drawing the player to the screen
    Gr = CreateGraphics()
    _backbuffer = New Bitmap(_resWidth, _resHeight)
    _bmpPlayer = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Ship)
    XPos = (Width / 2)
    YPos = 500
    Gr.DrawImage(_bmpPlayer, XPos, YPos, _sourceRec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)


    StartGameLoop()

End Sub
Private Sub Spaceinvaders_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    Do Until Intsound = 0
        Snd.Kill("Sound" & Intsound)
        Intsound -= 1
    Loop
    Dispose()
    End
End Sub
Private Sub Spaceinvaders_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove

    _mouseX = e.X
    _mouseY = e.Y

End Sub
Private Sub Spaceinvaders_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown

    If (290 + 110 < _mouseX Or _mouseX < 290 Or 336 + 63 < _mouseY Or _mouseY < 336) Then

    Else
        _paused = False
    End If


End Sub

'Starfield Background Generation
Private Sub CreateStarField(numStars As Integer)
    _stars.Clear()
    For i = 1 To numStars
        _stars.Add(New Point(_r.Next(0, Width), _r.Next(0, Height)))
    Next
End Sub


'Runs the actual game over and over again until it is stopped
Sub StartGameLoop()

    Do While _isRunning = True

        Application.DoEvents()

        LivesCheck()
        SetMoveDir()
        MovePlayer(_moveDir)
        'Start the drawing events & FPS Counter
        DrawGraphics()


    Loop

    Do While _isRunning = False
        Application.DoEvents()


    Loop

End Sub

'Subs to do with player creation and movement
Private Sub GetPlayer(ByVal dir As Int16)
    Select Case dir
        Case 1 'Upfacing Direction
            _bmpPlayer = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Ship)
            _sourceRec = New Rectangle(0, 0, 85, 50)
            PlayerH = 50
            PlayerW = 85
        Case 2 'Downfacing Direction
            _bmpPlayer = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Ship)
            _sourceRec = New Rectangle(0, 0, 85, 50)
            PlayerH = 50
            PlayerW = 85
        Case 3 'Left Facing Direction
            _bmpPlayer = New Bitmap(My.Resources.ShipLeft)
            _sourceRec = New Rectangle(0, 0, 96, 76)
            PlayerH = 76
            PlayerW = 96
        Case 4 'Right Facing Direction
            _bmpPlayer = New Bitmap(My.Resources.ShipRight)
            _sourceRec = New Rectangle(0, 0, 96, 76)
            PlayerH = 76
            PlayerW = 96
    End Select
End Sub
Sub SetMoveDir()
    If GetKeyState(Keys.W) = True Then _moveDir = 1
    If GetKeyState(Keys.A) = True Then _moveDir = 3
    If GetKeyState(Keys.S) = True Then _moveDir = 2
    If GetKeyState(Keys.D) = True Then _moveDir = 4


    If GetKeyState(Keys.Space) = True Then _fire = True
    If GetKeyState(Keys.P) = True Then
        If _pauseNum = 0 Then
            _paused = True
            _pauseNum = 1
        ElseIf _pauseNum = 1 Then
            _paused = False
            _pauseNum = 0
        End If
    End If

    If GetKeyState(Keys.W) = False And
       GetKeyState(Keys.A) = False And
       GetKeyState(Keys.S) = False And
       GetKeyState(Keys.D) = False Then
        _moveDir = 0
    End If

    If _moveDir <> 0 Then _lastDir = _moveDir
End Sub
Private Sub MovePlayer(ByVal dir As Int16)

    Select Case dir
        Case 1
            If YPos <= 0 Then
            Else
                YPos -= _movementSpeed
            End If


        Case 2
            If YPos >= 544 Then
            Else
                YPos += _movementSpeed
            End If


        Case 3
            If XPos <= -2 Then
            Else
                XPos -= _movementSpeed
            End If


        Case 4
            If XPos >= 606 Then
            Else
                XPos += _movementSpeed
            End If

    End Select

End Sub


'Draw the stuff to the screen
Sub DrawGraphics()
    If _paused = True Then

        Gr.DrawString("Paused", New Font("Verdana", _pausedText), New SolidBrush(Color.White), New Point(235, 256))

        If (290 + 110 < _mouseX Or _mouseX < 290 Or 336 + 63 < _mouseY Or _mouseY < 336) Then
            Gr.DrawString("Play", New Font("Verdana", 25), New SolidBrush(Color.White), New Point(290, 336))
        Else
            Gr.DrawString("Play", New Font("Verdana", 25), New SolidBrush(Color.Red), New Point(290, 336))
        End If

        'Copy BackBuffer To Graphics Object
        Gr = Graphics.FromImage(_backbuffer)
        'Draw BackBuffer to the screen
        Try
            _backBufferGr = CreateGraphics()
            _backBufferGr.DrawImage(_backbuffer, 0, 0, _resWidth, _resHeight)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex)
            _isRunning = False
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        Gr.Clear(Color.Black)


        'Runs when the game is unpaused
    ElseIf _paused = False Then

        Gr.Clear(Color.Black)
        'Draws Stars to the screen
        DrawStars()

        'Draws Enemies to the screen
        EnemyDraw()

        'Draws bullets to the screen
        BulletDraw()

        'Draws Explosions
        Expslostion()

        'Draw the player
        DrawPlayer()

        'Draws lives to the screen
        DrawHUD()


        'Copy BackBuffer To Graphics Object
        Gr = Graphics.FromImage(_backbuffer)
        'Draw BackBuffer to the screen
        Try
            _backBufferGr = CreateGraphics()
            _backBufferGr.DrawImage(_backbuffer, 0, 0, _resWidth, _resHeight)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
            _isRunning = False
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        Gr.Clear(Color.Black)
        GC.Collect()
        _fire = False
        WriteLog()
    End If
End Sub
Sub BulletDraw()
    If _bulletNum = 0 Then
        _bulletNum = 0
    Else
        For i = 1 To _bulletNum
            _bulletArray(i).Move(i)
        Next

    End If

    If _cooldown < 2 Then
        _cooldown += 1
    Else : If _fire = True Then
            _bulletNum += 1
            _bulletArray(_bulletNum) = New Bullet
            _bulletArray(_bulletNum).Spawn(_bulletNum, 4)
            _cooldown = 0

        End If : End If
End Sub
Sub EnemyDraw()
    If EnemyNum = 0 Then
        EnemyNum = 0
    Else
        For i = 1 To EnemyNum
            EnemyArray(i).Move()
        Next
    End If


    If _spawnNum < SpawnSpd Then
        _spawnNum += 1
    Else
        Points += 5
        EnemyNum += 1
        EnemyArray(EnemyNum) = New Enemies
        EnemyArray(EnemyNum).Spawn()
        _spawnNum = 0
    End If

End Sub
Sub Expslostion()

    If ExploNum = 0 Then
        ExploNum = 0
    Else
        For i = 1 To ExploNum
            ExploArray(i).Animation()
        Next
    End If

End Sub
Sub DrawStars()
    For Each pt As Point In _stars 'Loops until all the stars are added to the form background
        Dim num = _random.Next(1, 6) 'Randomly Picks a number
        Dim numSize = _random.Next(1, 3)
        If num = 1 Then 'Picks a colour based on the number picked
            Gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, New Rectangle(pt, New Size(numSize, numSize)))
        ElseIf num = 2 Then
            Gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, New Rectangle(pt, New Size(numSize, numSize)))
        ElseIf num = 3 Then
            Gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.DimGray, New Rectangle(pt, New Size(numSize, numSize)))
        ElseIf num = 4 Then
            Gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.DarkOrange, New Rectangle(pt, New Size(numSize, numSize)))
        ElseIf num = 5 Then
            Gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, New Rectangle(pt, New Size(numSize, numSize)))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub DrawPlayer()
    If _moveDir = 0 Then
        _bmpPlayer = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Ship)
    Else
        GetPlayer(_lastDir)
    End If
    _bmpPlayer.MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia)
    Gr.DrawImage(_bmpPlayer, XPos, YPos, _sourceRec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
End Sub
Sub DrawHUD()
    Select Case Lives
        Case 3
            Gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 510, 5, 150, 10)
        Case 2
            Gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 510, 5, 100, 10)
        Case 1
            Gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 510, 5, 50, 10)
    End Select

    Gr.DrawString("Ships Destroyed: " & EnemiesKilled, New Font("Verdana", 10), New SolidBrush(Color.White), New Point(5, 5))
    Gr.DrawString("Score: " & Points, New Font("Verdana", 10), New SolidBrush(Color.White), New Point(5, 20))
End Sub

Sub WriteLog()
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath() & "\" & "Variables" & ".Log")

    sw.WriteLine("--------Variables Log--------")
    sw.WriteLine("")
    sw.WriteLine("Sounds Playing: " & Intsound)
    sw.WriteLine("")
    sw.WriteLine("Window Resolution: " & _resWidth & " " & _resHeight)
    sw.WriteLine("Game Running: " & _isRunning)
    sw.WriteLine("")
    sw.WriteLine("Player Postion: " & XPos & " " & YPos)
    sw.WriteLine("Player Size: " & PlayerW & " " & PlayerH)
    sw.WriteLine("Player Movement Speed: " & _movementSpeed)
    sw.WriteLine("PLayer Last Direction: " & _lastDir)
    sw.WriteLine("")
    sw.WriteLine("Bullets Being Fired?: " & _fire)
    sw.WriteLine("Number Of bullets spawned: " & _bulletNum)
    sw.WriteLine("")
    sw.WriteLine("Number of enemies spawned: " & EnemyNum)
    sw.WriteLine()
    sw.WriteLine("--------Bullet Variables--------")
    sw.WriteLine("Bullet Number  X     Y")
    For i = 1 To _bulletNum

        sw.WriteLine(i & "            " & _bulletArray(i).X & "  " & _bulletArray(i).Y)

    Next

    sw.WriteLine("--------Enemy Variables--------")
    sw.WriteLine("Enemy Number  X     Y")
    For i = 1 To EnemyNum

        sw.WriteLine(i & "           " & EnemyArray(i).X & "  " & EnemyArray(i).Y)

    Next

    sw.Close()
    sw.Dispose()

End Sub
Sub LivesCheck()
    If Lives = 0 Then
        _isRunning = False
        Gameover.Show()
    End If
End Sub
End Class





Public Class Bullet
Dim _bulletX, _bulletY As Int16
Dim _bmpBullet As Bitmap = My.Resources.bullet1
Dim _bulletRec As New Rectangle
Dim _bulletSpd As Int16 = 4
Dim _enemyNum As Int16
Dim _active As Boolean = True

Function X()
    Return _bulletX
End Function
Function Y()
    Return _bulletY
End Function

Sub Spawn(ByVal i As Int16, ByVal s As Int16)

    Spaceinvaders.Intsound += 1
    With Spaceinvaders.Snd
        .Name = "Sound" & Spaceinvaders.Intsound
        .PlaySound(2, False)
    End With
    _bulletSpd = s
    _bulletX = Spaceinvaders.XPos + (Spaceinvaders.PlayerW / 2)
    _bulletY = Spaceinvaders.YPos + (Spaceinvaders.PlayerH / 2)
    _bmpBullet = My.Resources.bullet1
    _bmpBullet.MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia)
    Spaceinvaders.Gr.DrawImage(_bmpBullet, _bulletX, _bulletY, _bulletRec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

End Sub

Sub Move(ByVal bulletNum As Int16)
    If _active = False Then
        Me.Finalize()
    Else

        _enemyNum = Spaceinvaders.EnemyNum
        For i = 1 To _enemyNum
            Dim EnemyRect As Rectangle
            EnemyRect = Spaceinvaders.EnemyArray(i).Rectangle


            If (_bulletRec.IntersectsWith(EnemyRect)) Then
                If Spaceinvaders.EnemyArray(i).Invc >= 40 Then
                    Spaceinvaders.EnemyArray(i).Kill(-10, -10)
                    _active = False
                    Spaceinvaders.Points += 500
                    Spaceinvaders.CollitionDetc.WriteLine("Enemy Num: " & i & " & " & "Bullet Num: " & bulletNum & "   - HIT")
                    _bulletX = -100
                    _bulletY = -100
                    _bulletRec = New Rectangle(-100, 100, 1, 1)
                    Spaceinvaders.Intsound += 1
                    With Spaceinvaders.Snd
                        .Name = "Sound" & Spaceinvaders.Intsound
                        .PlaySound(3, False)
                    End With
                    Dim enemyX, enemyY As Int16
                    enemyX = Spaceinvaders.EnemyArray(i).X
                    enemyY = Spaceinvaders.EnemyArray(i).Y
                    Spaceinvaders.ExploNum += 1
                    Spaceinvaders.ExploArray(Spaceinvaders.ExploNum) = New Explo()
                    Spaceinvaders.ExploArray(Spaceinvaders.ExploNum).Spawn(enemyX, enemyY)
                    Me.Finalize()

                End If
            End If
        Next

        If _bulletY <= 0 Then
            _bulletX = -100
            _bulletY = -100
        Else
            _bulletY -= _bulletSpd
            _bmpBullet.MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia)
            Spaceinvaders.Gr.DrawImage(_bmpBullet, _bulletX, _bulletY)
            _bulletRec = New Rectangle(_bulletX, _bulletY, 16, 16)
        End If
    End If


End Sub
End Class




Public Class Enemies
Dim _enemyX, _enemyY As Int16
Dim _bmpEnemy As Bitmap = My.Resources.InvaderSkullWhite
Dim _moveNum As Int16 = 0
Dim _active As Boolean = True
Dim _tempInvc As Int16 = 0
Dim EnemyRect As Rectangle

Function X()
    Return _enemyX
End Function
Function Y()
    Return _enemyY
End Function
Function Kill(ByVal x, ByVal y)
    _enemyX = x
    _enemyY = y
    _active = False
    EnemyRect = New Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1)
    Me.Finalize()
End Function
Function Invc()
    Return _tempInvc
End Function
Function Rectangle()
    Return EnemyRect
End Function

Sub Spawn()
    Dim rand As New Random

    _enemyY = 3
    _enemyX = rand.Next(10, 600)

    Select Case rand.Next(1, 5)
        Case 1
            _bmpEnemy = My.Resources.InvaderSkullWhite
        Case 2
            _bmpEnemy = My.Resources.InvaderSkullRed
        Case 3
            _bmpEnemy = My.Resources.InvaderSkullGreen
        Case 4
            _bmpEnemy = My.Resources.InvaderSkullYellow
    End Select
    _bmpEnemy.MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia)
    Spaceinvaders.Gr.DrawImage(_bmpEnemy, _enemyX, _enemyY)
    Move()

End Sub

Sub Move()
    If _active = False Then
        Me.Finalize()
    Else
        If _tempInvc < 40 Then
            _tempInvc += 1
        End If



        If _moveNum < 10 Then
            _moveNum += 1
            _bmpEnemy.MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia)
            Spaceinvaders.Gr.DrawImage(_bmpEnemy, _enemyX, _enemyY)
        Else
            If _enemyY >= 700 Then
                Spaceinvaders.Lives -= 1
                _enemyX = -5
                _enemyY = -5
            Else
                Dim randX As New Random
                _enemyY += 5
                Select Case _enemyX
                    Case _enemyX <= 5
                        _enemyX = _enemyX + randX.Next(1, 4)
                    Case _enemyX >= 600
                        _enemyX = _enemyX + randX.Next(-4, -1)
                    Case Else
                        _enemyX = _enemyX + randX.Next(-4, 4)
                End Select

                _bmpEnemy.MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia)
                Spaceinvaders.Gr.DrawImage(_bmpEnemy, _enemyX, _enemyY)
                EnemyRect = New Rectangle(_enemyX, _enemyY, 64, 64)
            End If
            _moveNum = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class




Public Class Sounds
Public Declare Function MciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer
Dim _appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
Private _oName As String = Nothing

Public Property Name As String
    Set(value As String)
        _oName = value

    End Set
    Get
        Return _oName
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub PlaySound(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal repeat As Boolean, Optional vol As Integer = 35)

    If repeat = True Then
        MciSendString("Open " & GetFile(id) & " alias " & _oName, 0, 0, 0)
        MciSendString("Play " & _oName & " repeat", CStr(0), 0, 0)

    Else
        MciSendString("Open " & GetFile(id) & " alias " & _oName, CStr(0), 0, 0)
        MciSendString("Play " & _oName, CStr(0), 0, 0)

    End If
    'Set Vol
    MciSendString("Open " & GetFile(id) & " alias " & _oName, CStr(0), 0, 0)
    MciSendString("setaudio " & _oName & " volume to " & vol, CStr(0), 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Function GetFile(ByVal id As Integer) As String

    Dim path As String = ""

    'Here is where you put the sound paths so that your game can play sounds

    Select Case id
        Case 0 'Menu Background Music
            path = _appPath & "\Audio\Menu.mp3"
        Case 1 'Ingame Background Music
            path = _appPath & "\Audio\InGame.mp3"
        Case 2 'Fire Spund
            path = _appPath & "\Audio\Lazer.mp3"
        Case 3 'Expolsion sound
            path = _appPath & "\Audio\Expolsion.mp3"
    End Select

    path = Chr(34) & path & Chr(34)

    Return path

End Function

Public Sub Kill(ByVal song As String)
    MciSendString("close " & song, CStr(0), 0, 0)
    _oName = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: FYI There's no such thing as VBA.NET. Either you're doing VBA, or you're doing VB.NET.

Comment: Did ya upload enough code there Butch?  You should rarely store the graphic object.  Always dispose of it when done.  Dispose your images when done, too.

Comment: Also please use the standard uploader (click the 'Image' icon in the toolbar) to insert an image in your post.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I don't think that works for reputation 1 users.  They need at least 10 reputation.

Comment: @LarsTech possible... but odd, given how many times I've edited 1-rep users' posts to include the missing `!` that would make an `i.stack.imgur` url show up as an image.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon : They can still upload the image, but it will only be put as a link because they do not have the privileges to post viewable images. We do though, which is why we can edit their posts to fix it.

Comment: Your code is begging for more object types. Reminds me of my experimentations with XNA Game Studio - consider looking into how XNA projects abstract away drawable content and integrate game loop concerns like `Update` and `Draw`. That said, consider `Using` blocks everywhere an `IDisposable` is involved, rather than explicit disposal. Also the `Shared` stuff worries me, should be instance variables AFAICT.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I tried to post it as an image but my rep is too low.

Comment: The error message is: System.OutOfMemory: Out of memory. at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 Status)  at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 Width, Int32 height)  at SpaceInvaders.Spaceinvaders.DrawGraphics()   @Andrew Morton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone trying to help me fix the problem. I fixed the out of memory error by changing this bit of code:

```
If _bulletNum = 0 Then
        _bulletNum = 0
    Else
        For i = 1 To _bulletNum
            _bulletArray(i).Move(i)
        Next

    End If
```

To this:

```
If _bulletNum = 0 Then
        _bulletNum = 0
    Else
        Dim skipbullet As Int16
        skipbullet = _bulletNum - 50
        If skipbullet >= 1 Then
            For i = skipbullet To _bulletNum
                _bulletArray(i).Move(i)
            Next
            For i = 1 To skipbullet
                _bulletArray(i).Kill()
            Next
        Else
            For i = 1 To _bulletNum
                _bulletArray(i).Move(i)
            Next
        End If


    End If
```

Comment: `If _bulletNum = 0 Then _buttetNum = 0`???  Why not just `If _bulletNum > 0 Then` run the else code.

Comment: Honestly don't know why I wrote that :D

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're done with an object that implements IDisposable in almost all cases you should probably call it (there are exceptions outside the scope of this answer).  For note, A "using" statement always calls Dispose when it's done (so you're Graphics calls that are using a using are good on that front).

Where I see potential problems are the places you're using a class wide variable and resetting new Bitmap's onto it (I don't think the old one's get disposed and as a result I think they're hanging out there and slowly eating up your memory).

```
 _bmpPlayer = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Ship)
```

See if something like this helps:

```
If _bmpPlayer IsNot Nothing Then
    _bmpPlayer.Dispose()
End If

_bmpPlayer = new Bitmap(My.Resources.Ship)
```

That said, if you're using these same images over and over I would probably store them and re-use them as opposed to re-writing a new Bitmap from the resource every time.